# errbot: scripted plugin installation for docker?

Tags: errbot

I have a Dockerfile to run errbot, looking for a way to script plugin installation.  The documentation only seems to list the manual `!repos install ...` method.

Is there any way for automatic plugin installation from git repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use the BOT_EXTRA_PLUGIN_DIR config parameter and put any plugins you want to preload there.
https://github.com/errbotio/errbot/blob/master/errbot/config-template.py#L85

Comment: Thanks, that's one way, but I'd have to pull them locally in this case when building the docker image? I guess that's doable...

Comment: OK modified the plugin's code to pick up config from environment variables and all working well, thanks @gbin !

Answer (score 0):

If you've initialized Docker swarm mode (even if just on the one Docker host), you can use Docker Configs to pull in files to a container at run-time rather than baking them into the Docker image.

For your specific use case, check out the Docker image https://github.com/swarmstack/errbot-docker which does exactly what you are looking for.